# Custom html table

Tags: javascript, html-table

I want to make a small program using Javascript, I want to make a web-page that consists of a ranking-table where some participants can sort the table where the most important item will be at the top of the table and the least important item will be at the bottom via pressing some control buttons.

At the beginning, all the items will at same level:

[image]

If the user press Up button of item1, item1 will be raised up one level and the other items will shift to the left:

[image]

If I press the same button again, item1 will be raised one level up and a star will be placed in between at rank 2:

[image]

I am not good at Javascript and I have no idea how to achieve this, here is what I have done so far:

```
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Begin
function moveUp()
{

}
function moveDown()
{

}
//  End -->
</script>
</HEAD>


<BODY>

<table border="1">

<tr>
<th>Rank
</th>
<th colspan="5">
<p align="center">The Criteria
</th>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>
<p align="center">1
</td>

<td>
<form name="form1" method="post" style="margin: 0; text-align: center;"> 
<input type="button" name="Up1" value="Up" onclick="moveUp();"> Item 1
<input type="button" name="Down1" value="Down" onclick="moveDown();">
</form>
</td>

<td>
<form name="form2" method="post" style="margin: 0; text-align: center;"> 
<input type="button" name="Up2" value="Up" onclick="moveUp();"> Item 2
<input type="button" name="Down2" value="Down" onclick="moveDown();">
</form>
</td>

<td>
<form name="form3" method="post" style="margin: 0; text-align: center;"> 
<input type="button" name="Up3" value="Up" onclick="moveUp();"> Item 3
<input type="button" name="Down3" value="Down" onclick="moveDown();">
</form>
</td>

<td>
<form name="form4" method="post" style="margin: 0; text-align: center;"> 
<input type="button" name="Up4" value="Up" onclick="moveUp();"> Item 4
<input type="button" name="Down4" value="Down" onclick="moveDown();">
</form>
</td>

<td>
<form name="form5" method="post" style="margin: 0; text-align: center;"> 
<input type="button" name="Up5" value="Up" onclick="moveUp();"> Item 5
<input type="button" name="Down5" value="Down" onclick="moveDown();">
</form>
</td>

</tr> 
</table> 



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might want to look at [rentacoder.com](http://rentacoder.com) - this is basically asking to write an entire program.  You probably ought to get further than that so you can ask more specific questions here.

Comment: I just want the idea not the entire program

Comment: @Renesis: link correction: rentacoder.com has moved to vworker.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start for you.

Change your `onclick` attributes to use `.call()`. This just lets you set the value of `this` in the functions you're calling to the value of the first argument you pass to `.call()`. (In this case, the element that received the event.)

```
<input type="button" name="Up1" value="Up" onclick="moveUp.call(this);"> Item 1
<input type="button" name="Down1" value="Down" onclick="moveDown.call(this);">
```

Then these functions should give a basic idea of how it could work. Probably could use some tweaks like making it so that you can't add more rows than there are cells you're sorting.

```
var table = document.getElementById( 'mytable' );
var filler = document.createElement( 'td' );
filler.className = 'filler';
filler.innerHTML = '*';
```

```
function moveUp() {
    var cell = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    var row = cell.parentNode;
    var row_above;
    if( row.rowIndex === 1 ) {
        row_above = table.insertRow( 1 );
        row_above.insertCell( 0 );
        update_row_numbers();
    } else {
        row_above = table.rows[ row.rowIndex - 1 ];
    }
    if( row_above.cells[ 1 ] && row_above.cells[ 1 ].className === 'filler' ) {
        row_above.removeChild( row_above.cells[ 1 ] );
    }
    row_above.appendChild( cell );
    if( row.cells.length === 1 ) {
        if( row.rowIndex < table.rows.length - 1 ) {
            row.appendChild( filler.cloneNode( true ) );
        } else {
            table.deleteRow( table.rows.length - 1 );
            update_row_numbers();
        }
    }
}
```

```
function moveDown() {
    var cell = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    var row = cell.parentNode;
    var row_below;
    if( row.rowIndex === table.rows.length - 1 ) {
        row_below = table.insertRow( table.rows.length );
        row_below.insertCell( 0 );
        update_row_numbers();
    } else {
        row_below = table.rows[ row.rowIndex + 1 ];
    }
    if( row_below.cells[ 1 ] && row_below.cells[ 1 ].className === 'filler' ) {
        row_below.removeChild( row_below.cells[ 1 ] );
    }
    row_below.appendChild( cell );
    if( row.cells.length === 1 ) {
        if( row.rowIndex > 1 ) {
            row.appendChild( filler.cloneNode( true ) );
        } else {
            table.deleteRow( 1 );
            update_row_numbers();
        }
    }
}
```

```
function update_row_numbers() {
    for( var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++ ) {
        table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML = i;
    }
}
```

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/v9ujy/3/

**EDIT:** Updated to prevent rows with the star from being at the beginning and end of the sorted rows.

Comment: Sorry mate, they closed it before I give you the +300 rep :(

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: That's alright. Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `jQuery` and `jQuery UI` and all the available plugins. You may find something on there that fits your needs.

I'm thinking along the lines of drag'n'drop support to move your rows up and down.

Comment: `jQuery` should be an option and not a solution. Just saying `use jQuery` does not help those who are beginning and have no idea of what is going on. Answers like this are responsible for those poor beginners that think they "know how to code in jQuery" and have no idea that jQuery is just a javascript tool.

Comment: I would have hoped the OP would know how to use google and be capable of doing a little research for themselves. I didn't say "use jQuery", I said "take a loook at ..."

Answer (score 1):

I won't give the complete solution, but instead I will say that should have asked how to move an element from one parent to another, and then you can apply the button login as you wish.

You can accomplish that by using an element [`appendChild` function](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_appendchild.asp)

The code bellow will place the element `form2` into the first line of your table (which is the parent element of the `form1` element).

```
document.form1.parentElement.appendChild(document.form2)
```

You should be able to improve the logic by adding unique ids to your elements, so that you can manipulate them by using the `getElementById` function from the `document` and also you should consider using a javascript framework such as [`jQuery`](http://jquery.com/) or [`Prototype`](http://www.prototypejs.org/) to help you manipulate the DOM elements