# check if a cell of table contains a certain form

Tags: javascript

I want to check if a specific cell in a table contains a specific form using JavaScript.

Here is what I have done:

```
for(var i = 1; i >= mainTable.tBodies[0].rows[2].length; i++)
{
    if(mainTable.tBodies[0].rows[2].cells[i].elements[0] == document.getElementById("my_form"))
    {
        var cellIndex = i;
        alert("cell" + i + " contains the form");
        break;
    }
}
```

`"my_form"` is actually inside cell number `1`, but the if-statement is always false despite it should be true at `i = 1`. How can I achieve this in JavaScript?

**EDIT:**

Here is the whole code:

```
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- Begin

//var mainTable = document.getElementById("mainTable");
var index_Skill = 1;
var index_Speed = 1;
var index_Age = 1;
var index_Strength = 1;
var index_Height = 1;

function moveUp(theForm)
{
    if(theForm == "form_Skill")
    {
        if(index_Skill == 1)
        {
            // get the max index of the table
            var newIndex = Math.max(++index_Skill, ++index_Speed, ++index_Age, ++index_Strength, ++index_Height);

            // insert a new row
            var newRow = mainTable.tBodies[0].insertRow(newIndex);

            // shift the rows one level down
            for(var i = newIndex; i > 1; i--)
            {
                mainTable.tBodies[0].moveRow(i - 1, i);
            }

            // delete (skill) from the old index
            var cellIndex;
            for(var i = 1; i >= mainTable.tBodies[0].rows[2].length; i++)
            {
                if(mainTable.tBodies[0].rows[2].cells[i].elements[0] == document.getElementById("form_Skill"))
                {
                    cellIndex = i;
                    alert(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
            for(var i = cellIndex; i >= mainTable.tBodies[0].rows[2].length; i++)
            {
                mainTable.tBodies[0].rows[2].cells[i].innerHTML = mainTable.tBodies[0].rows[2].cells[i+1].innerHTML;
            }
            //mainTable.tBodies[0].rows[2].cells[mainTable.tBodies[0].rows[2].length].innerHTML = "";

            // add (skill) to the new index
            var newCell = mainTable.tBodies[0].rows[1].insertCell(0);
            newCell.innerHTML = 1;
            newCell.setAttribute("align", "center");
            var newCell = mainTable.tBodies[0].rows[1].insertCell(1);
            var obj = document.getElementById(theForm).cloneNode(true);
            newCell.appendChild(obj);

            // fixes the id's
            for(var i = 1; i <= newIndex; i++)
            {
                mainTable.tBodies[0].rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML = i;
                mainTable.tBodies[0].rows[i].cells[0].setAttribute("align", "center");
            }

        }
    }
}


function moveDown(theForm)
{

}


//  End -->
</script>
</HEAD>
```

```
<BODY>

    <table id="mainTable" name="mainTable" border="1">

        <tr>
            <th>Rank
            </th>
            <th colspan="5">
                <p align="center">The Criteria
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p align="center">1
            </td>

            <td>
                <form name="form_Skill" method="post" style="margin: 0; text-align: center;"> 
                    <input type="button" name="Up1" value="Up" onclick="moveUp('form_Skill');"> Skill
                    <input type="button" name="Down1" value="Down" onclick="moveDown('form_Skill');">
                </form>
            </td>

            <td>
                <form name="form_Speed" method="post" style="margin: 0; text-align: center;"> 
                    <input type="button" name="Up2" value="Up" onclick="moveUp('form_Speed');"> Speed
                    <input type="button" name="Down2" value="Down" onclick="moveDown('form_Speed');">
                </form>
            </td>

            <td>
                <form name="form_Age" method="post" style="margin: 0; text-align: center;"> 
                    <input type="button" name="Up3" value="Up" onclick="moveUp('form_Age');"> Age
                    <input type="button" name="Down3" value="Down" onclick="moveDown('form_Age');">
                </form>
            </td>

            <td>
                <form name="form_Strength" method="post" style="margin: 0; text-align: center;"> 
                    <input type="button" name="Up4" value="Up" onclick="moveUp('form_Strength');"> Strength
                    <input type="button" name="Down4" value="Down" onclick="moveDown('form_Strength');">
                </form>
            </td>

            <td>
                <form name="form_Height" method="post" style="margin: 0; text-align: center;"> 
                    <input type="button" name="Up5" value="Up" onclick="moveUp('form_Height');"> Height
                    <input type="button" name="Down5" value="Down" onclick="moveDown('form_Height');">
                </form>
            </td>

        </tr> 
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: You wrote javascript code. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `tr` element itself doesn't have a `.length` property.

This:

```
for(var i = 1; i >= mainTable.tBodies[0].rows[2].length; i++)
```

...should get the length from `cells` instead:

```
  // right here -----------------------------------v
for(var i = 1; i >= mainTable.tBodies[0].rows[2].cells.length; i++)
```

And a `<td>` doesn't have an `elements` property. I assume you intend `.children`, depending on the browsers you're supporting.

```
  // ------------------------------------v
mainTable.tBodies[0].rows[2].cells[i].children[0]
```

Comment: @Samuel: That's correct, except for in IE8 and lower, which includes comment nodes. You can read the [compatibility notes from quirksmode here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html).

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: You have `.rows[2]`. If you want the second row, use `.rows[1]`. http://jsfiddle.net/3PNR6/

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: The HTML you posted in the question only has 2 rows. The row with the `<th>` elements is `rows[0]` and the row with the `<td>` elements (and the forms) is `rows[1]`.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: Oh, I see. Is it your intention that the row with the forms will always be last? If so, I'd just select the last row directly. `var rows = mainTable.tBodies[0].rows; var last = rows[ rows.length - 1 ]; rows.children[ 0 ];`

Comment: @patrick not necessary to be the last one, this is what I am trying to achieve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933905/custom-html-table-javascript

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: [Have a look at this.](http://jsfiddle.net/v9ujy/2/) Should give you a start anyway.

Comment: @patrick giving me a start? Are you kidding me? this is just what I want, it is really AWESOME. Thank you man you saved my day. post your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933905/custom-html-table-javascript and I will start a bunty with +300 tomorrow and I will give it to you. Thanks :)

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: Sure thing, will do. Glad I could help. :o)

Comment: @Patrick one more thing, I want to improve your code so that the star signs only appears in between the items, i.e the first row and last row of the table should not be star sign

Comment: I tried this at the end of `moveUp` method but didn't work: `if(row.rowIndex === table.rows.length - 1) table.removeChild(table.rows[table.rows.length - 1]);`

Comment: Yay, I did it myself and it works. At the end of `moveUp` function I add `if(row.rowIndex === table.rows.length - 1 && table.rows[table.rows.length - 1].cells.length == 2) table.deleteRow(table.rows.length - 1);` `update_row_numbers();` and at the end of `moveDown` function I add `if(row.rowIndex === 1 && table.rows[1].cells.length == 2) table.deleteRow(1);` `update_row_numbers();`

Comment: oops, sometimes it deletes rows with items inside it :\

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: I've got a solution for you. I'll update the answer I left on the other question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a small typo i guess in indices:

```
for(var i = 0; i <= mainTable.tBodies[0].rows[2].length; i++)
{
    if(mainTable.tBodies[0].rows[2].cells[i].elements[0] == document.getElementById("my_form"))
    {
        var cellIndex = i;
        alert("cell" + i + " contains the form");
        break;
    }
}
```